AWS DMS: the RDS is not seen for engine Oracle (same AZ, same VPC)
Have a Oracle RDS (19c Standard Two, CDB - which is supported) and I'm creating a Data Provider for engine=Oracle, but I can't see the DB to select it. It just says "You don't have any RDS databases in Europe (Frankfurt)." (but I do)
When I create the data provider for target (PostgreSQL), the corresponding RDS is seen fine.
The 2 RDS are in the same AZ (eu-central-1), same VPC, same 3 private subnets, have the same VPC security groups, only the engine is different. The secret is correct and the certificate is loaded, rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 (same for both). The Ora DB has just 1 associated IAM role (rds-s3-integration), the Postgres none.
If I tried entering connection details manually: I can create the provider, but then it fails to connect in the migration project when starting Schema Conversion (web-based, not SCT).
If I edit the security groups temporarily to allow all IPv4 TCP 51521: same issue. I don't know if I can add rule for DMS only (e.g. have no replication instance yet, still stuck at schema conversion).
If I try a different service like "AWS Backup", on-demand, type RDS, I can see both DBs to select.
If I try DMS: Create Endpoint, I still see just the target PG DB, and not the Ora.
Any idea what else can be wrong  ?

Does your company subscribe to AWS Support? They would be able to look into the issue.

Unfortunately not (yet), tried to get a trial accepted and used repost.aws in the meantime. But eventually I kind of guessed the cause (CDB). It wasn't so clearly mentioned in the documentation that it won't work (or I didn't configure it enough)...

It seems it doesn't work when the DB is "Oracle Standard Edition Two (CDB)",even if "Single-tenant configuration" (a CDB with a single PDB). Had to make a new non-CDB DB, and I also changed the port to default 1521 to be sure, and this one was visible in both sections.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
